# Mac OS X terminal prompt displaying foreign hostname (or: What is Stacey's iPhone doing in my Terminal?)

Tags: macos, terminal

I opened my Terminal today and saw this:

```
StaceysiPhone6s:~ jcz$
```

[image]

- Who is Stacey?
- Why is she in my Terminal?
- What happened?
- What should I be worried about?
- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

At some point, your network assigned StaceysiPhone6s an IP address. Then, your laptop got that IP address. Your Mac then looked up the DHCP logs to find out who 'owned' that IP and found "StaceysiPhone6s". So, it used that info to set the local `hostname` value.

Example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Comment: Perfect, very reassuring. Thanks for not being so alarmist!

Comment: oh, I forgot to add: BURN YOUR LAPTOP AND ANY USB DEVICE THAT YOU EVER PLUGGED IN! And you should probably burn any flat surface it ever touched for good measure.

Comment: Not taking any chances, I'll start with self-immolation

Comment: Good man, you'll go far in infosec!

Comment: 1) What dhcp logs? 2) It's more likely OS X evaluating dhcp option 12.

Comment: But that still leaves the question: Who is Stacey and what was she doing with her iPhone on your network?

Comment: This answer rather misses the core bug, that OSX is trusting the DHCP server to tell your machine its own name rather than using whatever name you gave it, or a default one. From any reasonable privilege model the DHCP server is at best untrusted and preferably considered malicious.